# Write multiple lists to CSV

Tags: python, csv

I have two lists:

```
x = [['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f'], ['g','h','i']]
y = [['j','k','l'], ['m','n','o'], ['p','q','r']]
```

I'd like to write lists `x` and `y` to a CSV file such that it reads in columns:

Col 1:
a 
b
c

Col 2:
j
k
l

Col 3:
d
e
f

Col 4:
m
n
o

etc.  I'm not really sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `zip` to do the transpose and `csv` to create your output file, eg:

```
x = [['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f'], ['g','h','i']]
y = [['j','k','l'], ['m','n','o'], ['p','q','r']]

from itertools import chain
import csv
res = zip(*list(chain.from_iterable(zip(x, y))))
with open(r'yourfile.csv', 'wb') as fout:
    csvout = csv.writer(fout)
    csvout.writerows(res)
```

If you have unequal lengths, then you may wish to look at [itertools.izip_longest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) and specify a suitable `fillvalue=` instead of using the builtin `zip`

Comment: No need for the `list(...)` constructor